# How to call a function in my package every time code is inserted?

Tags: function, coffeescript, package, atom-editor

I'm writing an Atom package, and I'd like to know how to get a function that my package exposes and that is accessible via a context menu call to be called every time the user types code into the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I can assume that you are after one of thoose callbacks:

`onDidChange` - is called when the buffer changes(Synchronous)
https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.2.4/TextEditor#instance-onDidChange

or `::onDidStopChanging(callback)` for heavy tasks - called 300ms after change(Asynchronous) 
https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.2.4/TextEditor#instance-onDidStopChanging